# Angular and Jasmine tests with mock $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a method that uses the `$http` service by mocking the `$httpBackend`.  My method works fine in my app, but I can't get the test to work.  Here is the test code that does not work (I do not get any result, and the URL is correct:

```
describe("authHelper", function() {
    var webHelper;
    var url;
    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function(){
        pingResponse = {
            principal: null,
            authenticated: false,
            servlet:true,
            timestamp:1468325333070
        };
        angular.mock.module('provisioning');

        inject(function ($injector) {
            webHelper = $injector.get('webHelper');
        url = webHelper.buildUrl('/ping');
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.whenGET(webHelper.buildUrl('/ping')).respond(200, pingResponse);
        });
    });

    it("should pass if setup is correct", inject(function(authHelper) {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    console.log(url);
        authHelper.isAuthenticated().then(
        function(data){ alert(data); },
        function(data){ alert(data); }
    );
    }));
```

Here is the method that I am testing - this works when I have my app service running on a server, but the mock is not working.  I have 10 other tests that work fine, but can't seem to get the mock working.  I see the URL logged in the console but that's it:

```
var isAuthenticated = function(){
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get(webHelper.buildUrl('/ping')).then(function(data){
    console.log("isauth got");
    console.log(data);

        if(data.data.authenticated){
            d.resolve(true);
        } else {
            d.resolve(false);
        }
    }, function(errorData){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(errorData);
    d.resolve(false);
});

    return d.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call `httpBackend.flush();` to flush pending requests after calling `authHelper.isAuthenticated()`.

See Angular documentation for more details:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend